# flask app searching logic for similar word

Tags: python, html, flask

I am a flask beginner and recently I am doing my first project which is searching cocktails using flask and API.
So, here is the snippet of my flask code

```
@app.route('/search' ,methods=[ "POST"])
def search():
    value = request.form['search']
    cocktailAPI = requests.get(
        f'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s={value}'
    )
    value = request.form['search']
    print(value)
    return f'ff'
```

My thought is like searching things on google, no matter what I am typing google can find the most relative information for me.

Is it possible to do that? for instance, if I type 'margarite' in which 'margarita' is correct, the flask will try to find the correct word in my API and give me a response.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is called [fuzzy search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), and is a whole problem on its own.

This is not so hard though, considering that the list of existing cocktails is quite already known.

So here a way you could follow:

1. Build a list of existing cocktail names; you could for instance retrieve the whole list through Thecocktaildb API (though it requires a contribution), or create a list manually (as this is not likely to evolve much)
2. Once user enters a name, return the closest cocktail names from your list, using some distance metrics of your own (Wikipedia article provides some clues)
3. Request Thecocktaildb API for this cocktail.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help! This information is very helpful to me!

Comment: In fact, outside of `joblib` and `flask`, there are some Python libraries that provides fuzzy search utility, see [the Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/search/?q=fuzzy+search). I've tested none, this will be up to you ;)